# How to use Network Time Protocol (NTP) on Android?

Tags: clock, date-and-time

Is there any way to sync time using NTP with a time server such as [NIST Internet Time Servers](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi) on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ClockSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.org.amip.ClockSync) accepts any given NTP server you input and syncs your device time with it. The app itself is not new but works fairly well to this day.

Comment: FYI: the app is not available on the Play Store anymore, future readers won't be able to download and use it (you may still be able to see the entry on the Play Store if you have installed it before).